# How to create a blended straight-line/curved section boundary using svg or css?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

For my app, I'm creating a sign-up page with a nonstandard section boundary. You can see the effect I'm trying to achieve here:
[image]
It's not a simple arc -- it has two straight lines but also an arc in the middle.

From what I have read, the best way to achieve something like this is with an SVG. The problem is, that white area is going to have an image covering the entire thing. For demo purposes I'll use a light blue color. If you use a standard `div` with a `background-image` property, the white of the SVG isn't transparent, so you get this:
[image]

Cue a couple hours of reading later on `shape-outside` and `clip-path` properties, and this is the latest approach I've tried (note I'm using React with styled-components):

```
const LeftContainer = styled(FlexContainer)`
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
  /* background: linear-gradient(360deg, #FFFFFF 24.95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50.95%), url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/TestImage.png); */
`;
const RightContainer = styled(FlexContainer)`
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: ${colors.secondary600}; */
  float: left;
   /* background-image: url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SignUpBackground.svg); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;    
  clip-path: url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SignUpBackground.svg#sidebar);
`;
```

There's still a gap, but not only that, the SVG shape has the bottom third cut off:
[image]

The only way I've been able to make the left container fill that extra space is by making the right container `position: absolute`, but this is going to cause issues with the login form I plan to add to the right side (and it doesn't seem to solve the issue of cutting off the bottom third of the svg).

Is there a way I can keep the right container in the flow of the page, show 100% of the svg, and ensure the left container is flush with the right container?

EDIT:
Here is the SVG code:

```
<svg width="708" height="1056" viewBox="0 0 708 1056" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<clipPath id="sidebar">
<path d="M144.5 0H799.5V1056H144.5L23.4254 775.169C0.402533 721.768 -5.09917 662.442 7.71089 605.718L144.5 0Z" fill="#16979A"/>
</clipPath>
</svg>
```

And here is the React component so far (early stage of build as you can see):

```
const SignUpPage = (props) => {
  return ( 
    <Container>
      <LeftContainer>
        {/* Site logo and marketing copy, promo bubbles to go here. This side should be the one to shrink */}
      </LeftContainer>
      <RightContainer flexDirection="column" justify="center">
        {/* Signup/Login form to go here */}
      </RightContainer>
    </Container>
   );
}
```

EDIT2:
I've tried implementing the solutions from the answers below, but so far each one has at least one issue. Beginning with ccprog's suggestion, I was a little uncertain because the code didn't seem to match up with the description of the approach, but I attempted to implement it and came up with this result: (code first, then resulting image)

```
const Container = styled(FlexContainer)`  
    height: 523px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #FFFFFF 24.95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50.95%), url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SignUpImage.jpg);
    background-position: top right 282px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;

const LeftContainer = styled(FlexContainer)`
    flex-grow: 1;
`
const RightContainer = styled(FlexContainer)`
    width: 354px;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox="0 0 708 1056" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M144.5 0H799.5V1056H144.5L23.4254 775.169C0.402533 721.768 -5.09917 662.442 7.71089 605.718L144.5 0Z" fill="%2316979A"/></svg>');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
`
```

[image]

As you can see, this doesn't actually fill the full height of the screen, even on the right side, and the left side image is really cut off (the left side image is a problem in all of the solutions as you'll see).

Next, I tried implementing the 2nd of chrwahl's solutions. This one came a bit closer (the right side looks great) but the left side image has some issues:

```
const Container = styled(FlexContainer)`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SignUpBackground.svg),
  linear-gradient(360deg, #FFFFFF 24.95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50.95%), url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/SignUpImage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right, left;
  background-size: contain, cover;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;
```

[image]

I'm not sure if it comes through in this image, but the whole left side of the screen is blank here, so it seems the image is not starting from the left edge even though the position is specified as left. The issue is worse with `background-size: 40%, 70%`:
[image]

Comment: We'll need more information to help with this. Is there a fixed aspect ratio for the combination of both sides, or do you want to achieve a responsive solution? Is there further HTML content on the left side, or is it only the image? Where, exactly, will the mentioned form elements go? Please show at least the relevant HTML (or HTML-producing) code and the code of the SVG itself.

Comment: It will be responsive, but the left container should be the one to shrink. The right container (with the svg) will contain the login form itself, so it needs to retain its width. The left container will only contain some marketing copy and the site logo. I will provide the SVG code and the (minimal) HTML-producing code that currently exists.

Comment: @ccprog I've added the requested code

Comment: In reference to my answer and your new edit. Now you have three different elements in the background-image property. That is fine but you need the same number of items in the background-position and -size... That is why it does not behave like expected.

Comment: There are still only 2, one image on the left and the svg on the right. I just used a different image in subsequent images to illustrate the point more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of terminology: let's call the width of the area covered by the SVG shape at top and bottom the "right side minimum", and the width covered in the middle the "right side maximum".

The way I understand your question, the right area a) has a constant width and b) should always show the complete SVG shape. From that follows that it **must** have a constant height and an aspect ratio of 708 : 1056. That makes it easy to compute the needed sizes, the most important being that the ratio between the right side minimum and the right side maximum is 564 : 708.

Now, I would suggest to solve you problem by moving the left-side image as a background-image to the outer container element, with a width that ensures it goes under the curved part, i. e. 100% minus 564px (or a fixed fraction). The left container element, containing the promo content gets a width of 100% minus 708px, and the right container a width of 708px (or a fixed fraction). (For simplicity, the containers get identified by a class name matching their component name)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 523px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, white, red);
    background-position: top right 282px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.container-right {
    width: 354px;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox="0 0 708 1056" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M144.5 0H799.5V1056H144.5L23.4254 775.169C0.402533 721.768 -5.09917 662.442 7.71089 605.718L144.5 0Z" fill="%2316979A"/></svg>');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-left">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-right">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use other px size values as long as the ratio between them is maintained.

And if you do **not** want to show the full SVG, but only make sure the curve on the left remains completely visible, add the following attribute to the root `<svg>` element:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"
```

When changing the aspect ratio of the right container, this will have the same effect as the CSS `cover`, plus the area of the `viewBox` is always ligned up with the left side. This will work only if the aspect ratio will move to a higher height in relation to the width. If the aspect ratio gains in width, equal parts of the curve will be cut of at the top and bottom - but the other choice would be that it isn't wide enough to cover the right side.

If you go that route, remember that you can only know the width of the area between maximum and minimum right side if you set a fixed height in advance. CSS just cannot use the height of an element to compute a width value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my initial question to reflect what happens when I attempt to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can place both the image and the SVG as a background in CSS. Here are three different examples. In the first I have the same issue as you do. The second will always work, but part of the image is covered by the SVG and cut off. The third is a matter of testing for different sizes.

Now, my examples are not THE SOLUTION. Takeaway here is: You can have more background images in your CSS. Notice that the images are separated by a comma. The number of values in the background-position and -size must/can match the number of images. The configuration depends on the size, aspect ratio, the image quality and the purpose of the image. You need to figure out what matches your scenario.

The SVG in the example looks like this (notice the viewBox has been changed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 798 1056" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M144.5 0H799.5V1056H144.5L23.4254 775.169C0.402533 721.768 -5.09917 662.442 7.71089 605.718L144.5 0Z" fill="#16979A"/>
</svg>
```

```css
.login {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNzk4IDEwNTYiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xNDQuNSAwSDc5OS41VjEwNTZIMTQ0LjVMMjMuNDI1NCA3NzUuMTY5QzAuNDAyNTMzIDcyMS43NjggLTUuMDk5MTcgNjYyLjQ0MiA3LjcxMDg5IDYwNS43MThMMTQ0LjUgMFoiIGZpbGw9IiMxNjk3OUEiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cgo='),
  url('https://via.placeholder.com/800x600');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right, left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.size1 {
  background-size: contain, contain;
}

.size2 {
  background-size: contain, cover;
}

.size3 {
  background-size: 40%, 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="login size1"></div>
<div class="login size2"></div>
<div class="login size3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my initial question to reflect what happens when I attempt to implement this solution.

Comment: I updated my anser to include the part about the number of values in the background properties.